# Other text disappearing when linking span

Tags: html, css, text

I am creating a basic webpage, where I want a header logo made of text to be linked. Under this, I would like to have a slogan that stays as regular, non linked text. This doesn't seem to be working as when I put a link on just the header (even inside of a `span`), as the slogan text just disappears. I tried making them different blocks of text, but doing so puts them on different lines, ruining the aesthetic I would like (Header text with slogan underneath)

```css
:-moz-selection {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00ffaa;
}
::selection {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #00ffaa;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00ffaa;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00D486;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ADFFE2;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00ffaa
}
.thing {
  background: #141414;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
   width: 100%;
}
a.Header {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.Header:hover {
  color: #dbdbdb;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#bodycontainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 200%;
  width: 65%;
}

.navigation {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navigation li a {
    color: #00ffaa;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
    color: #adffe2;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/6PQ1Mtl.png">
  <center>
    <div id="bodycontainer">
    </div>
  </center>

  <div class="thing"><font face="hamster">
        <span><a class="Header" href="">Header</a></span><br><span class="slogan">tagline</span>
     </font><font face="fenice">
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="https://google.com">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">Comics</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </font>
</div>
      </body>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: The `<font>` tag has been deprecated and is not supported in HTML5. Replace it with any valid tag (`span`?) and use CSS to specify the `font-face`. The same goes for `<center>`. use: `text-align`, `float`s or *flexbox*.

Comment: Oh man thanks! That actually solved the problem O_o

Comment: I know. Whenever I can, I test before advising.